# Visual Studio Lightswitch HTML Client validation fails

Tags: javascript, lightswitch-2013

I have this piece of JavaScript code that's supposed to force a string of text to upper-case characters, but it won't work. I know it hits a breakpoint when I set it, but the code doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to.

I'm new to JavaScript. What am I missing here?

```js
myapp.AddEditVehicle.beforeApplyChanges = function (screen) {
    // force string to uppercase
    screen.Vehicle.RegNum.toUpperCase();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to tackle this in JavaScript on the client side, you need to use the following code:

```
myapp.AddEditVehicle.beforeApplyChanges = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    screen.Vehicle.RegNum = screen.Vehicle.RegNum.toUpperCase();
};
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to do this in c# on the server side, you can add the following RegNum_Validate code by selecting the Write Code option on the designer screen for your Vehicle.lsml entity:

```
partial void RegNum_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
{
    // results.AddPropertyError("<Error-Message>");
    if (this.Details.Properties.RegNum.IsChanged) 
    {
        this.RegNum = this.RegNum.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind that the Write Code option for the RegNum_Validate general method will only be available if you have the Server project perspective selected at the bottom of the entity designer.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful and please can you click the tick to accept it as an answer